# Vue.JS: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, mysql, api, vue.js, axios

All i want is to get all data from API to my Province Lists. here's my Index.vue

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="prov in provinces" :key="prov.id">
   <td>{{ prov.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ prov.name }}</td>
   <td>
    <div class="btn-group">
     <router-link 
      :to="{ name: 'bansos.edit', params:{id: bansos.id}}"
      class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info"
      >Edit</router-link>
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">
       Delete
     </button>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
                       
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import {onMounted, ref} from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        // reactive state
        let provinces = ref([]);

        onMounted(() => {
            // get data from api endpoint
            axios.get('http://www.emsifa.com/api-wilayah-indonesia/api/provinces.json')
// here's the error
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.response)
            });

        });

        return{
            provinces

        }

    }
    
}
</script>
```

This is the result of the API I want to get the data for, from http://www.emsifa.com/api-wilayah-indonesia/api/provinces.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "ACEH"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "SUMATERA UTARA"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "SUMATERA BARAT"
  },
  {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "RIAU"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "JAMBI"
  }
]
```

I'm new to vue.js. I hope someone can give me a hint and solve this problem

so this is the stack trace, i don't know where the problem is.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at mergeConfig (:3000/@modules/axios.js:1308:24)
    at Axios.request (:3000/@modules/axios.js:1431:12)
    at Axios.<computed> [as get] (:3000/@modules/axios.js:1521:17)
    at Function.wrap [as get] (:3000/@modules/axios.js:7:15)
    at :3000/src/views/bansos/Index.vue:13:19
    at callWithErrorHandling (:3000/@modules/common/runtime-dom.esm-bundler-01c9ef75.js:8185:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (:3000/@modules/common/runtime-dom.esm-bundler-01c9ef75.js:8194:21)
    at Array.hook.__weh.hook.__weh (:3000/@modules/common/runtime-dom.esm-bundler-01c9ef75.js:3418:29)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (:3000/@modules/common/runtime-dom.esm-bundler-01c9ef75.js:8386:47)
```

Comment: Which line is giving you this error?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts sorry i'm forgot.. line 60, on axios endpoint and .then

Comment: Could you post a stack trace?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with your code, it may be a bug with the version of axios you're using. I searched and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606882/how-can-i-grab-a-csv-with-axios-in-a-svelte-app) as well as a recent [GitHub issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4153) for axios.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install axios@0.21 --save` to change your version of axios

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.